# Bulk Insert from local Drive to remote Sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert csv file from local server to remote based sql server. I gave permission to this folder directory. I am able to bulk insert into locally installed sql server but on remote based sql server getting below error.

> Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\G\data_files\2023-10-17_17-19.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

I have remote based sql server's following permissions'
server based: **bulkadmin** and **public**
database based: **datareader**, **datawriter**, **dbowner**, and **public**.

Is anyone encounter this error before, kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Paths are relative to the SQL Server *host* not the machine sending the query. You are trying to `BULK INSERT` a file that is hosted locally on the SQL Server's host.

Comment: @ThomA I am unable to understand your response. Kindly elaborate it.

Comment: You'll need to share the local directory and access via UNC path (e.g. `\\YourLocalMachine\G\data_files\2023-10-17_17-19.csv"` if the G directory is shared with the same name). You'll need to also grant permissions on the share to the SQL Server account. Alternatively, you could use the command-line BCP utility instead of T-SQL `BULK INSERT` to push the data to SQL Server, in which case the local path will work.

Comment: The `BULK INSERT` statement refers to paths from the perspective of the SQL Server machine, not your client machine. Maybe use `SqlBulkCopy` in Powershell or C# instead, or bcp.exe.

Comment: I am using python to insert data from file to table using **BULK INSERT** @Charlieface

Comment: When you specify a path in your SQL, it's relative from the perspective of the SQL Server. `C:` means drive C on the SQL Server host, it *does not* mean C drive on what ever machine you are using that sends the SQL statement you wrote to the SQL Server. As you mention that you have a remote server involved then, presumably, by `C:` you mean Drive C on the Remote server; this is an incorrect assumption. If you were using UNC paths, you effectively have `\\YourSQLServerHost\C$\G\...` as the path you want to load, *not* `\\RemoteServer\C$\G\...`

Comment: Alternatively, if you *do* mean a path on the SQL Server host, this suggests that the service account SQL Server is running under doesn't have access to the path. You'll need to ensure it *does* have permission.

Comment: @ThomA thank you for your response, I don't have file on remote server. I have file on local machine's drive **C:**. I know if the file on the share folder then it is okay but on local drive getting error.

Comment: Then, if the file is located on the SQL Server, the SQL Server service account does not have access to that path. As mentioned in my prior comment, you'll need to grant the service account access.

Comment: Please be clear with your comments, does `I have file on local machine's drive C:` mean your local drive or the SQL Servers? If it's not in the disc of the SQL Server, then read the earlier comments. You cannot refer "C:" from some other machine.

Comment: For local files you can't use that version of bulk (it only works for server relative files), but have to insert manually or if python supports streaming bulk, you might be able to use that.